# how to do union between 2 queries in oracle db

Tags: oracle

I want to get union the result of 2 queries in oracle ..

```
SELECT
   name 
FROM
   TABLE 
WHERE
   age = 10 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH next 10 ROWS ONLY 
UNION
SELECT
   name 
FROM
   table2 
WHERE
   aage = 15 OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH next 10 ROWS
```

union gives me error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i get syntax error.

Comment: Is `where aage = 15 offset 10` correct?  Is the column actually `aage`?

Comment: yes, i am making dummy table full of data

Comment: Which Oracle database version do you use? 10g? 11g? 12c? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Queries should be wrapped with brackets:

```
(Select name from tab  where age = 10 offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only)
union
(select name from tab2 where age = 15 offset 10 rows fetch next 10 rows only)
```

Comment: @yarabyarab - Lukasz changed the table names to work with them - you need to change them back. Other than that his query is 100% correct. Your two problems are that you didn't wrap the queries in parentheses, which is needed because you've got a *row-limiting-clause* on each query, **AND** in your second query you were missing the word `ONLY` at the end of the *row-limiting-clause*. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Issues with your code:

1. `aage` should probably be spelled `age`
2. as explained by Lukasz Szoda, `union`ed query should be enclosed in parentheses (`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`)
3. missing keyword `only` (or `with ties`) at the end of the second query (`ORA-00905: missing keyword`)

Query:

```
(select name from table1 where age = 10 offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only)
union
(select name from table2 where age = 15 offset 10 rows fetch next 10 rows only)
```

NB: this syntax is available from Oracle 12c onwards. You can check the version that you are running with this query:

```
select banner from V$VERSION;
```

In the result, you should see something like: `Oracle Database <your version number>`

Comment: Please share the entire error message that you are getting.

Comment: This is not the entire error message. Please give the *complete error message* (that start with `ORA-...`), otherwise it will be very hard for anyone to help more...

Comment: i am using 12c .. but it still gives me syntax error

Comment: @yarabyarab: I might be repeating myself, but: please share the complete error message. Without the message, I cannot help (and, likely, no one else can)...